# ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"

Tags: sql, postgresql

**ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"** я получаю ошибку в POSTGRESQL. я пишу роллбек

`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column SET NOT NULL SET DEFAULT 'word';`

без **SET** у дефолтного значения я получаю **ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"** когда пишу это

`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column SET NOT NULL DEFAULT 'word';`

Answer (score 1):

По синтаксису [alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
where action is one of:
...
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name SET DEFAULT expression
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name DROP DEFAULT
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name { SET | DROP } NOT NULL
```

это разные действия и должны записываться как разные действия.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
    ALTER COLUMN my_column SET NOT NULL,
    ALTER COLUMN my_column SET DEFAULT 'word';
```

Comment: После записи их как разные действия, я получаю "ERROR: column "my_column" contains null values"

Comment: ну так разумеется если в таблице есть строки содержащие null - то как ставить not null? Обновите их предварительно, записав что-нибудь не null в эту колонку.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал update и сработало)